# Jelly module throwing internal server error

Tags: kohana, internals, jelly

The Jelly module throws a 500 internal error. I have no idea why it does this and how to solve this.

When I remove jelly module folder from the server or simply rename any of the Jelly module files, the error disappears (Kohana throws an error because Jelly Class is not found which is normal).

I don't understand why Jelly would throw an internal error, it just does not make any sense!

(The error does not come from the folders and files permissions. I made sure that they're all 755 and 644).

(Everything works fine locally - WAMP server)

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide what the error states?  You can find it in your apache error log on your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank your for your answers. The problem was solved somehow. I have no idea what happened.

It seemed to work when I removed `send_headers()` in the bootstrap but it really annoyed me because I needed it.

Then I replaced `Request::instance($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])` by `Request::instance()` in the `echo` in the bootstrap and it worked...

More info about the error logs there: http://forum.kohanaframework.org/comments.php?DiscussionID=6322&page=1

Answer (score 0):

Check you're on the latest version of Jelly.

Check all your files for syntax errors. If you don't get an error page returned from Kohana it's probably because you've crashed php in some way.

Sorry if this doesn't help, please post more code/debug info.